# Linear Regression : SSR equation

Tags: statistics

I've studied SST and the others but I saw the equation that $SSR=(n-1)(β_1)^2(S_x)^2$.

I want to know how the equation is done.
Thnks!!

Comment: I believe you'd want to put $\hat\beta_1$ for $\beta_1$. Then it should become clear.

Comment: what is beta hat..?

Comment: Beta1 "hat" is the estimate for Beta1

Answer (score 0):

In simple regression, we have

$$
\bar{y} = \hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\beta_1} \bar{x}
$$

by normal equations. Thus,

$$
\begin{align}
SSR &= \sum_{i=1}^n (\hat{y} - \bar{y})^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left( (\hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\beta_1}x_i) - (\hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\beta_1} \bar{x}) \right)^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left( (\hat{\beta_1})^2 (x_i - \bar{x})^2 \right) \\
&= (\hat{\beta_1})^2 \sum_{i=1}^n ( (x_i - \bar{x})^2 \\
&= (\hat{\beta}_1)^2S_{xx}
\end{align}
$$